# What is this tiny strawberry-like fruit found in a Southern Illinois lawn?

Tags: identification, lawn, fruits, weeds

I live in southern Illinois, and earlier today I noticed this small red fruit in my yard. It looks kind of like a strawberry, but it's the size of a small raspberry (about 1/4 inches in diameter).

[image: Small red fruit]

Does anyone have any idea what it is?

Comment: Hey Matt! Nice to see you on GL! I was almost positive this was a dupe, but I think I must remember IDing this weed by comment somewhere. I am assuming you weren't looking for methods of control, hence the short answer. If that would be useful, I can expand the answer.

Comment: The only other reference I could find was in [this question](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/13424/2984). I'm not really looking for weed control, since I'm renting the place and the whole yard is a mix of various clover-like plants. I was just wondering what it was. :)

Comment: I don't think the search engine picks up content from comments.

Comment: @J.Musser That's true, I was just double-checking for a duplicate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is [Mock Strawberry, *Duchesnea indica*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_strawberry). The fruits are edible, but rather tasteless. This is a common weed in much of the United States. Look for small, strawberry-like plants in your lawn, with long stolons connecting the individual crowns. These plants have five petaled yellow flowers. See comparison photos:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: FWIW: we have this plant in France, too. Easy to mix up with wood-strawberries.